# Jquery method for HTML <option> selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

what is the correct method for selecting any of these options in Jquery?

```html
<select>
  <option id="x" >A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
</select>

<div id="one"></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```javascript
$("#x").click(function(){
    $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

or select:

```javascript
$("#x").select(function(){
    $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

ps:
imagine I have 3 options and 3 divs to be fadeout. how can I select any of my 3 options for specific div?
like this:

```
<select>
<option id="x" >A</option>
<option id="y">B</option>
<option id="z">C</option>
</select>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

for option x I just want div one to be fadeout, for option y div two and for option z div 3

Comment: Not yet really clear to me what you want to do exactly. You could create a jsFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the html like this , you have to use id in select element

**HTML**

```
<select id="x">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
</select>
```

**Js**

```
$("#x").change(function(){
    $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

or 
`if you place id in option` do like this

```
$("#x").parent().change(function() {
    $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

**For updated  new Question** use id as data-attribute or common class in html

HTML

```
<select>
    <option id="x">A</option>
    <option id="y">B</option>
    <option id="z">C</option>
</select>
<div id="one" data-id="x">x</div>
<div id="two" data-id="y">y</div>
<div id="three" data-id="z">z</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find("option:selected")[0].id;
    //use some commaon class or use attrbute 
    //$(".commonClass").hide();
    $("[data-id]").hide()
    $("[data-id=" + id + "]").show();

}).change();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/snu6x4fu/3/)**

Comment: `change` event will never occur on `#x`

Comment: i did not put id in option

Comment: Still you've changed the HTML structure

Comment: make a sample in fiddle or somewhere

Comment: @nito  Updated check now.. but you have to make a connection b/w option and div (i used data attribute) then only we can hide and show div based based on option selection

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `change` event on the `select`:

```
$('#x').parent().on('change', function() {
// On selecting option

    $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
    // Fadeout element
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7jfk7rwq/1/)

Comment: @Balachandran Because, I don't want to change the `HTML` structure of OP

Comment: he mentioned  id in option **<option id="x" >**  you have to use  like $("#x").parent() or anything

Comment: @Balachandran I'm not blaming you

Answer (score 2):

do you want to do something like this??????    http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/2g2va6qx/

```
    $("#x").parent().change(function() {
       $("#one").fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

Comment: It's just for div "one". "y" shoud fadeout div "two" and "z" show fadeout div "three"